# Custom plus and minus quantity buttons in Woocommerce 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, product-quantity

I’m building custom WordPress and WooCommerce theme and adding custom plus and minus buttons to **Product page quantity field**. The buttons do update quantity input's value and I also receive "Item has been added to your cart" notification (on Product page) when I submit Add to Cart. But the cart page doesn’t show any items, neither says the cart is empty.

I can not work out which WooCommerce JS function I’m suppose to hook into, neither how to hook into it. Could I ask for help please?!
Thanks in advance!

My HTML layout:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <label class="quantity__label" for="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <div class="quantity__wrapper">
        <input type="button" value="-" class="quantity__button quantity__remove js-qty-remove" />
        <input
            type="text"
            id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>"
            class="input-text qty text quantity__input"
            step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>"
            min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"
            max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>"
            name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>"
            title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"
            size="4"
            pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>"
            inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>"
            aria-labelledby="<?php echo esc_attr( $labelledby ); ?>" />
        <input type="button" value="+" class="quantity__button quantity__add js-qty-add" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My custom jQuery function:

```
function quantityButtons() {
    var $qtyAdd = $('.js-qty-add'),
        $qtyRemove = $('.js-qty-remove'),
        $qtyInput = $('.quantity__input');

    $qtyAdd.on('click', addQty);
    $qtyRemove.on('click', removeQty);

    function addQty() {
        var $qtyInput = $('.quantity__input'),
        $qtyRemove = $('.js-qty-remove'),
        $i = $qtyInput.val();

        $i++;
        $qtyRemove.attr("disabled", !$i);
        $qtyInput.val($i);
    }

    function removeQty() {
        var $qtyInput = $('.quantity__input'),
        $qtyRemove = $('.js-qty-remove'),
        $i = $qtyInput.val();

        if ($i >= 1) {
            $i--;
            $qtyInput.val($i);
        } else {
            $qtyRemove.attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }

    $qtyRemove.attr("disabled", !$qtyInput.val());
}

quantityButtons();
```

Comment: If you need a plugin which adds ( - / + ) buttons for both product and cart page, I've just created one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/qty-increment-buttons-for-woocommerce/  It has great styling, a lot of customization options and instead of overriding templates, it uses only hooks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your First code part is made from a customization of `global/quantity-input.php` Woocommerce template code…

So for testing, I have changed partially that `global/quantity-input.php` template code with the following (very near to your code):

```
?>
<div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <input type="button" value="-" class="qty_button minus" />
    <input
        type="number"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>"
        class="input-text qty text"
        step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>"
        min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"
        max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>"
        title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"
        size="4"
        pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>"
        inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>"
        aria-labelledby="<?php echo esc_attr( $labelledby ); ?>" />
    <input type="button" value="+" class="qty_button plus" />
</div>
<?php
```

Now the necessary CSS and revisited jQuery code functions:

```
// Minimum CSS to remove +/- default buttons on input field type number
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'custom_quantity_fields_css' );
function custom_quantity_fields_css(){
    ?>
    <style>
    .quantity input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    .quantity input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .quantity input.qty {
        appearance: textfield;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'custom_quantity_fields_script' );
function custom_quantity_fields_script(){
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
        if ( ! String.prototype.getDecimals ) {
            String.prototype.getDecimals = function() {
                var num = this,
                    match = ('' + num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
                if ( ! match ) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return Math.max( 0, ( match[1] ? match[1].length : 0 ) - ( match[2] ? +match[2] : 0 ) );
            }
        }
        // Quantity "plus" and "minus" buttons
        $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.plus, .minus', function() {
            var $qty        = $( this ).closest( '.quantity' ).find( '.qty'),
                currentVal  = parseFloat( $qty.val() ),
                max         = parseFloat( $qty.attr( 'max' ) ),
                min         = parseFloat( $qty.attr( 'min' ) ),
                step        = $qty.attr( 'step' );

            // Format values
            if ( ! currentVal || currentVal === '' || currentVal === 'NaN' ) currentVal = 0;
            if ( max === '' || max === 'NaN' ) max = '';
            if ( min === '' || min === 'NaN' ) min = 0;
            if ( step === 'any' || step === '' || step === undefined || parseFloat( step ) === 'NaN' ) step = 1;

            // Change the value
            if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
                if ( max && ( currentVal >= max ) ) {
                    $qty.val( max );
                } else {
                    $qty.val( ( currentVal + parseFloat( step )).toFixed( step.getDecimals() ) );
                }
            } else {
                if ( min && ( currentVal <= min ) ) {
                    $qty.val( min );
                } else if ( currentVal > 0 ) {
                    $qty.val( ( currentVal - parseFloat( step )).toFixed( step.getDecimals() ) );
                }
            }

            // Trigger change event
            $qty.trigger( 'change' );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

The quantity buttons "plus" and "minus" work perfectly and are displayed this way:

[image]

Products are added to cart with the correct quantity:

[image]

if you change the quantity field value with plus and minus buttons, the "Update cart" button is activated when any quantity field change.

[image]

When you click on "Update cart", the quantities as correctly updated.

Comment: Many thanks Loic, your code works great! I have seen similar jquery function in one of the wocommerce plugins, but I was not applying it correctly to my theme. Your detailed advice is very helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: It's working for me. Thanks for the answer. Upvote from my side.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Could you take a look at this question please ? merci beaucoup  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784840/persons-field-plus-minus-buttons

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Show Buttons */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_quantity_plus' );

function display_quantity_plus() {
     echo '<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_quantity_minus' );

function display_quantity_minus() {
     echo '<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>';
}
//Note: to place minus @ left and plus @ right replace above add_actions with:
//add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_quantity_minus' );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_quantity_plus' );

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_cart_quantity_plus_minus' );

function add_cart_quantity_plus_minus() {
 // Only run this on the single product page
 if ( ! is_product() ) return;
 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){   

     $('form.cart').on( 'click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {

        // Get current quantity values
        var qty = $( this ).closest( 'form.cart' ).find( '.qty' );
        var val   = parseFloat(qty.val());
        var max = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'max' ));
        var min = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'min' ));
        var step = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'step' ));

        // Change the value if plus or minus
        if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
           if ( max && ( max <= val ) ) {
              qty.val( max );
           } else {
              qty.val( val + step );
           }
        } else {
           if ( min && ( min >= val ) ) {
              qty.val( min );
           } else if ( val > 1 ) {
              qty.val( val - step );
           }
        }

     });

  });

  </script>
```

```
 //add css
 .single-product div.product form.cart .quantity {
      float: none;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
 }
```