# Custom plus and minus quantity buttons in on Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

I tried using this answer code "[Custom plus and minus quantity buttons in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367826/custom-plus-and-minus-quantity-buttons-in-woocommerce-3/52378023#52378023)" to add custom **plus** and **minus** buttons to the quantity field on my products in Woocommerce and it works fine.

But it adds **plus** and **minus** buttons to any all quantity fields even in cart.

My problem is that I use a third party plugin that displays a flyout cart that already uses its own **plus** and **minus** buttons, so I have two **plus** and **minus** buttons instead of one.

How can I have the **plus** and **minus** buttons just on the product pages?

Comment: What you are asking is just too broad… You can't have a customization on a template that works globally and at the same time enable a plugin that uses it's own customizations from this same template. You should need instead to override all related templates located in `single-product` > `add-to-cart` folder

Answer (score 0):

you can use one if() for Troubleshooting,

```
if(is_product()){
do somthings,
}else{
do other somthings,
}
```

Comment: This will not work as it's a global template that is overridden and the OP's plugin display the flyout cart everywhere. So it's much more complicated.