# How to change default quantity selector on woocommerce cart page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using *[Custom plus and minus quantity buttons in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367826/custom-plus-and-minus-quantity-buttons-in-woocommerce-3/58764739#58764739)* answer code from @Krishna, that changes the appearance of the default quantity selector on woocommerce product page.

When I change:

```
woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity
```

to

```
woocommerce_after_quantity_input_field
```

it is showed on both the pages but it wasn't actually functional on the cart page.

How do I apply it to the cart page as well?

Comment: Have you tried with this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378023/10447197

Comment: Yes but it unfortunately isn't working. The css removes the default ▲ and▼and nothing happens after that

Comment: Did you use all of the code in the link response above? You should revert to the changes you made so far and try using the link code.

Comment: No it does work! I had to add ```<input type="button" value="-" class="qty_button minus" />``` ```<input type="button" value="+" class="qty_button plus" />``` to the quantity-input.php but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use [LoicTheAztec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378023/15184469) and add `<input type="button" value="-" class="qty_button minus" /> <input type="button" value="+" class="qty_button plus" />` to quantity.php because yours is probably missing it if the answer doesn't work outright.

Edit: not quite sure how to mark this as answered since it isn't actually my answer